# mvc attribute routing with optional parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, custom-attributes

I got the following attribute set

```
    [Route("{country}/{state}/{city}/listing/{name?}/{address}/{id}", Name = "ViewListing")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
    ...
    }
```

following url works fine

```
http://localhost:16949/ca/on/london/listing/something/1830-avalon-street/d46fc94f-9a90-460a-b18f-7443db3c1897
```

however the following gives 404, even though the name parameter is set as optional

```
http://localhost:16949/ca/on/london/listing/1830-avalon-street/d46fc94f-9a90-460a-b18f-7443db3c1897
```

I also have other routes defined that have the same number of parameters with different structure and those do not fire either(and they should not), for clarity, here are the other routes

```
CITY
{country}/{state}/{city}
{country}/{state}/{city}/{type}
{country}/{state}/{city}/bedrooms/{parameters}
{country}/{state}/{city}/{type}/bedrooms/{parameters}
{country}/{state}/{city}/area/{area}
{country}/{state}/{city}/area/{area}/bedrooms/{parameters}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option route parameter should be at last. In you case, when you no pass the {name}, The route will not match "{country}/{state}/{city}/listing/{address}/{id}". And then not route match the second url, so it will give you 404